# Trying to display a component template

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a vue component, the /people is a json of all the people on the website like so:

```
    <template>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" v-for="people in persons">
            <div class="c-item">
                <a href="" class="ci-avatar">
                    <img src="img/demo/contacts/1.jpg" alt="" class="hoverZoomLink">
                </a>

                <div class="c-info">
                    <strong>@{{ people.name }}</strong>
                    <small></small>
                </div>

                <div class="c-footer">
                    <button class="waves-effect"><i class="zmdi zmdi-person-add"></i> Add
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>


    <script>
        export default {

            data: function(){
                return {
                    persons: []
                }
            },

            mounted: function()
            {
                this.getPeople();
            },

            methods:
            {
                getPeople: function() {
                    axios.get("/people").then(function(response) {
                        this.persons = response.data;
                    }.bind(this));
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

That code is in Example.vue, and in my app.js I have the following code:

```
    Vue.component('all-people', require('./components/Example.vue'));


    const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
    });
```

Now In my blade file I have the following HTML

```
    @extends('layouts.main')
    @section('content')
        <div class="container">

            <div id="app">
                <all-people></all-people>
            </div>
        </div>
    @stop
```

When I load my page I'm getting no errors, but the template ins't displaying, here is the source:

```
    <div class="container">
        <div id="app"><!----></div>
    </div>
```

I am trying to bind the component, to the div with the ID of 'app'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `all-people` component inside the `div` with `id = app`, like following:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="app">
       <all-people></all-people>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can get more details on how to use in the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#ad).

Comment: I have. See above in the OP.